# MarkerCluster OR SuperCluster OR Vector OR

Tags: leaflet, openlayers

currently I'm working with many GeoJSON-Point-Objects. For my testing I use Leaflet with plugins (MarkerCluster, SuperCluster) and to compare them I tried OpenLayes with a cluster-vector solution.

I'm generating 30000 points with a nodeJS server and this delivers the points to the clients over a restAPI.

question: what is the best way to display more 
than 30000 points in a browser without a mapserver?